# display imageicon in Jlabel

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, jlabel

I'm doing a program in Netbeans

.. and I need to display the content of the folder (there are images) in a JPanel

... display every image in jlabel

.... I did this code, but its not working

...... I create a interface with a JButton and JPanel:

```
public class MyInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

    /** Creates new form NewJFrame1 */
    public MyInterface()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    private File files;

    private JFileChooser es = new JFileChooser();

    String path;
    JLabel label;

    public List<ImageIcon> pictures = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {

        if (es.showOpenDialog(jPanel1) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            files = es.getSelectedFile();
            path = files.getAbsolutePath();
            return;
        }

        label.setIcon(pictures.get(WIDTH));
        files = null;
        return;
    }

    private JLabel getLabel(BufferedImage[] images)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < images.length; j++)
        {
            pictures.add(new ImageIcon(images[j]));
        }
        label = new JLabel(pictures.get(0));
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        return label;
    }

    private JPanel draw()
    {
        JPanel panl = new JPanel();
        for (int j = 0; j < pictures.size(); j++)
        {
            panl.getBorder();
        }
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panl.addAncestorListener(null);
        panl.add(panl);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code so we can read it.

Comment: Please read [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). Do a little more research before asking a question.

Comment: I've formatted it for the OP. Now my eyes hurt less, but my brain hurts more.

Comment: i read the api two and tree times!but still not working....

Comment: Where is `jPanel1`, and the `initComponents()` method? This code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

hard to say something and wise

1) maybe there isn't any reason for create [JLabels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) and [JPanels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) on the fly

2) if you want to display only one `Image` in one moment then

- create [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)
- put there [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) and [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- use [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for `Image/BufferedImage`, put this `Icon` to the `JLabel`

3) if you want to display more than one Images (let's to say up to 20-50 `Images`) then use [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for `JLabels` contains `Icon`

4) if number of `Images` isn't limited somehow then use [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: yes this is what i want to do,to display more than one Image...  so the right way is to search GridLayout ?? thanks for help. plz if you have any guide.. plz give the link.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, your code doesn't compile as shown, and it's a bit of a mess. Some pointers though:

In `draw()`, you are adding a JPanel to itself, which is not a good sign. Then you return a different panel that has not been modified. Sort out the `panel` and `panl` naming to fix this.

In `getLabel()`, which isn't actually called anywhere, you return one label created from the first image. So you will only be able to display one of the images.

In `jButton1ActionPerformed` you return early if the user selects a file, so the path will be set but it's not clear that anything else happens.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a newbie in java,and i'm so confused, how i have to do every thing!

Comment: OK. Start simple, test each bit as you go, add stuff only when you are sure everything is working. Try the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)